# Getting notified about Android subscription cancellations

Tags: android, google-cloud-pubsub, in-app-subscription

Basically whenever a user subscribes, he is saved to our database. If for some reason a user decides to cancel, we need to update his status in or database.

On our iOS version, we are able to provide an api endpoint to our php server which takes care of updating the user status in our database. However, Google doesn’t seem to have something similar. Instead all I’ve found is Pub/Sub which appears to be unbelievably complicated (at least for someone like me who works mostly on the app code with Java) and which in addition is a paid service.

Are there any other options to be notified of such a simple subscription status change?

If not, do you know of any sample implementations of pub/sub that can be followed?

Answer (score 1):

**Real-Time Notifcations**

If you want to know in real time the evolutions of your users' subscriptions, you must use the [Real-time developer notifications](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/rtdn-reference) (so yeah, the Pub/Sub). In particular, this one: `SUBSCRIPTION_CANCELED`. It is quite harder to configure than the iOS ones, but then it's the same kind of work to analyse the received notifications.

I'm working at Purchasely where we've described [how to configure the Pub/Sub](https://docs.purchasely.com/stores-configuration/play-store) (you'll just have to change our url by your own, in the step 4 of "Creating a subscription on the topic").

Then you'll start receiving notifications from Google and you'll be able to know the evolutions of your users' subscriptions (as you're already doing with the [App Store Server Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications) if I understood correctly).

**Google Play Developer API**

Another way of knowing the state of your subscriptions is to implement a CRON-like job that'll check every X-period of times if the subscriptions with a past expiryTime has been renewed or not with [this Google API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions/get). The limitation of doing this (instead of the Real-Time Notifications) is that you won't know if someone has asked for a refund before the expiryTime (and you could let a person pay the equivalent of 3 days and benefit from the subscriptions for a year if that's the renewal period of your product).

**My recommendation**

Personally I would definitely go for the Real-Time Notifications.